# How to turn on auto search on VS Code on macOs?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using the Search functionality within Visual Studio Code on Windows, as I'm typing into the search textbox, it does autocomplete searching. On macOS, I have to hit the enter key for the search to happen.

Is there a way to turn on autocompletion of auto search in VS Code on macOS?

I'm currently on Big Sur. MBP 16" 2019.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have the `searchOnType` setting set to `false` on your Mac.

```
// Search all files as you type.
"search.searchOnType": true,

// When #search.searchOnType# is enabled, controls the timeout in 
// milliseconds between a character being typed and the search 
// starting. Has no effect when search.searchOnType is disabled.
"search.searchOnTypeDebouncePeriod": 300,
```

[image]

It was added as part of the **1.41** release (make sure to have at least this version):
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41#_update-search-results-as-you-type

> In full text search, results will now update as you type. This is especially helpful in scenarios like constructing complicated Regular Expression queries, where fast feedback on a query can help you to write the RegEx.
>
> **Note**: This feature can be disabled by setting `search.searchOnType` to `false`, and the delay between typing and searching can be adjusted with `search.searchOnTypeDebouncePeriod`, which defaults to 300 ms.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at this, where would I add this? I tried in `settings.json` but it highlights as `Unknown Configuration Setting`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney In settings.json would be the correct place. Check that you have a 1.41+ version of VS Code installed, as that's when that setting was added.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Either on the User or the Workspace settings.json (added image to my answer).

Comment: Thanks - the issue was the version. I had downloaded and was using VS Code from the downloads folder on my MBP which is classed as a read-only folder, so VS Code does not auto update. Who knew? Well, I do now - thanks again