# Why doesn't VS Code auto update on macOS?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I have VS Code on Windows and macOS, on Windows it auto updates but on macOS it doesn't.

How do I get VS Code to auto update on macOS?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

VS Code on macOS will not auto update if it's running from a read-only folder.

If you downloaded and are running VS Code from your **Downloads** folder, which is read-only, it will not auto update.

Solution:

When you've downloaded VS Code, drag the downloaded file to your applications directory and run it from there instead.

[image]

It will now auto update

Thanks to @gino mempin in the answer to my previous question for the inspiration [How to turn on auto search on VS Code on macOs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65421180/how-to-turn-on-auto-search-on-vs-code-on-macos#65421274)

Comment: This is not working for me. I've confirmed VS Code is in fact in my Applications folder, yet I continue to get the "Cannot update while running on a read-only volume. The application is on a read-only volume. Please move the application and try again. If you're on macOS Sierra or later, you'll need to move the application out of the Downloads directory. See this link for more information." warning.

Comment: @MarkGavagan try quitting Visual Studio Code, finding it in the Applications folder, holding down the command key ⌘ while dragging it to the Downloads folder, then dragging it back to the Applications folder. Mine was able to update after that, see: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/27928#issuecomment-306382650

Comment: Dragging from Downloads to Applications + restarting vscode worked for me.

Comment: Make sure to quit VS Code, not just close it.

Comment: This one work for me: Dragging VS code from download to application folder.

Comment: Why `Downloads` is read-only if files are written there when downloaded?

Comment: Quit VS Code (not just close it) worked for me!

Answer (score 60):

In case anyone encounter this and VS Code was **already** in your Applications Folder...

1. Quit VS Code in case it was running (make sure with CMD⌘+Q)
2. Hold CMD⌘ + drag (so that it moves the app instead of making a shortcut) the VS Code app back to the `Downloads` folder.
3. Hold CMD⌘ + drag the VS Code app back to the `Applications` folder.
4. Now update should be possible :)

Comment: I was like its already in application folder but its not working :D. Thanks man

Comment: After doing all the steps above, I still hafdto restart my MacBook to make the updates available.

Answer (score 16):

I solved my problem with this command:

> xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app

source: [naveendhanaraj.wordpress.com](https://naveendhanaraj.wordpress.com/2021/07/14/cannot-update-while-running-on-a-read-only-volume-the-application-is-on-a-read-only-volume-please-move-the-application-and-try-again-if-youre-on-macos-sierra-or-later-youll-need-to-move-the-ap/)

Answer (score 10):

1. Right-click on the app and locate it in finder:

[image]

2. And drag-n-drop to the `Applications` folder.
3. Restart VSCode

Answer (score 3):

2 ways of resolution:

- Way 1

Drag the vscode app icon from downloads to application if you have downloaded fresh

- Way 2

Hold CMD key and drag the vscode app icon from application to download and back to application

[Way 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5Ioe.png)

Comment: My VSCode is already in the Applications folder but I still encounter error. I used 'Way 2' and it worked. I don't know why but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Moving `VSCode` to `Applications` folder and then restarting Mac worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue even though my VS Code was in Applications folder. To solve the issue:

~ Exit the VS Code if open.

i. I moved the VS Code from `Applications` folder to `Downloads` folder completely (make sure you move it and not just create a copy of it. You can do that using command key file moving the VS Code)

ii. Moved the VS Code back from `Downloads` folder to `Applications` folder.

iii. Open the VS Code back again.

Comment: This worked for me perfectly! I am on Sonama 14.3 and the app was in Applications folder and yet I was getting: Cannot update while running on a read-only volume. The application is on a read-only volume. Please move the application and try again. If you're on macOS Sierra or later, you'll need to move the application out of the Downloads directory. This might mean the application was put on quarantine by macOS. See this link for more information.

Comment: moving back and forth works for me

Answer (score 1):

Solution if @StudioTime's solution is not working:

Terminal:

```bash
sudo chown $USER ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode.ShipIt/*
xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Settings
2. Privacy & Security
3. Select Full Disk Access
4. Check VS code then restart VS code and try install updates